# Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "asset" function

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, twig

I have a wordpress theme, building it with twig 2.0, using **webpack-encore-bundle** for assets. The problem is 'asset' is not working in html.

How can I use asset in img src tag to load my images?

I'm using PHP 7.3.0

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <img src="{{ asset('build/search.png') }}"/>
</div>
```

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .  '/vendor/autoload.php');

$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/view');


 
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
    'cache' => false,
    'debug' => (defined('WP_DEBUG') && true === WP_DEBUG),
    'assets' => [
        'base_path' => '/wp-content/themes/map_firemakers/assets/images',
    ],
]);
```

**WEBPACK.CONFIG.JS**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images'})
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/script.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()  
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })


;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: How does your composer.lock/composer.json looks like? Do you have the webpack dependancy there?

Comment: Wow, Twig in Wordpress! First time I see that! The asset function is from the `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension` namespace (at least in the version I use) can you verify that the class `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\AssetExtension` is loaded somehow. Also, can you show your composer files or the result of `composer show`?